# Lightbox JS and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just implemented some code into my home page to create a lightbox for my pictures. However, the internal css has somehow affected my overall style of the page. For example, when I hover over the main header, it moves to the side (just like how the rest of the images move). Also, it has caused my header to shift to the right and expose the background colour. I've put the `html`and css onto a codepen, so if any of you can identify my problem, I'd be v grateful!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Xmogdb

Comment: It looks like you can set `addToAll = false` and add the `fancybox` class only to targeted images. [Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/avPwwm).

Comment: Another method is to apply Fancybox only to images inside of `div.main` by changing your selector to `$('.main img')`. [Example here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOowGx).