# Hovering with CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

Can anyone help me fix my code so that the hover colour only applies to the navigation bar and not the pictures too. I've tried to specify this by having  `.a.main-nav:hover { ...}`etc in my code but that just gets rid of the hover altogether.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOowGx

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. If codepen is ever not accessible then your question will have no value to future visitors.

Comment: Similar concept as your previous question, [Lightbox JS and CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683861/lightbox-js-and-css). Check and experiment with your selectors. For reference, see [Selectors @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors).

Comment: @showdev I'm pretty much a beginner and didn't really understand your solution but thank you for your input!

Comment: I offered the MDN link in case you are interested in clearing up your misunderstanding of CSS selectors. Specifically, `.a.main-nav` will select any element with both classes "a" and "main-nav". What you want is to select an `<a>` element that is inside an element with class "main-nav", like `.main-nav a` (as seen in the answer from Akhilesh B Chandran).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
a:hover {
  background-color: #ffbc00;
}
```

Should be like this:

```
.main-nav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffbc00;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! :)